# What is an active node in a graph and how can it be identified?

Tags: graph, graph-theory

I don't understand exactly what an active node is and how I could identify one, you have an example in the image below
https://i.stack.imgur.com/zJ12z.png

I don't necessarily need a solution, but more of a definition or a good example

Answer (score 0):

The [Push-Relabel Maximum Flow Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Push%E2%80%93relabel_maximum_flow_algorithm) has the definition:

> For a fixed flow *f<sub>1</sub>*, a vertex *v ∉ {s, t}* is called **active** if it has positive excess with respect to *f<sub>1</sub>*, i.e., *x<sub>f</sub>(u) > 0*.

If that is the algorithm you are using to analyse the graph then you can use that definition; if you are using a different algorithm then you should consult the definitions for that algorithm and it will tell you how an "active" vertex is defined.

Comment: This is the algorithm, but what exactly is s and t?

Comment: @Bob If you click on the link you can read the definitions.